# How get id entity form

Tags: php, symfony

hello guy i went get id for y entity in field

this is `var_dump($form->getData());`

```
array (size=4)
      'region' => string 'ddsdd' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'zadzd' (length=5)
      'lastName' => string 'zdazd' (length=5)
      'Type' => 
        object(bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\Foo)[591]
          protected 'id' => int 2                        // how get this ID 
          protected 'type' => string 'Frein' (length=5)
```

thanx you

Answer (score 1):

In case this is doctrine entity you can access it by calling getId() method.

```
$form->getData()['Type']->getId()
```